# Adding a ribbon bar to the top of a graph with wxpython

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, ribbon

I am using `wxpython` and have been using used the ribbon bar template as shown [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/ribbon/ribbonbar_demo.py):

I have created a graph and would like to **place the ribbon bar at the top of the window above the graph.**

What I have managed to do so far is place a graph with a menu bar at the top. however, I would like to replace the menu bar with a ribbon bar.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx

class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,
                         'CanvasFrame',size=(550,350))

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit application')
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)


        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColour("WHITE"))
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.sizer.Add(menubar)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.canvas.draw()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = App(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Which compiles to the following:

[image: Menubar example]

Comment: What do you propose to put in the ribbonbar? `Quit` doesn't seem to justify a ribbonbar.

Comment: I am aiming to develop a GUI which will contain greater functionality. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a guide on how to do this task and have only managed to do this so far with a menu bar.

Comment: Download the wxpython demonstration programs. It has a working example of `wx.ribbon` https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.0.6/wxPython-demo-4.0.6.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I am already using the wx.ribbon working example which I have linked to in my post. I am using this as a template but can't insert a graph within the frame under the ribbon bar.

However, I will have a look at the other examples within the folder as they will help me with other aspects of the GUI.

Comment: If that is the case, then you should have shown that code in your question.